# Странности при работе со строками

Tags: python, строки

Известно, что для экономии памяти Python при работе со строками не создает разные объекты (по ссылкам передаёт в переменные адрес):

```
s1 = 'bar'
s2 = 'bar'
print(id(s1) == id(s2))
>>> True
s3 = 'bar'*2500
s4 = 'bar'*2500
print(id(s3) == id(s4))
>>> False
```

Почему так происходит?

Comment: Последний print возвращает True

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, поправил. Там в скобках должны были передаваться строки s3 и s4

Comment: А вообще самому стало интересно, потому что такая строчка выведет True: s3 = 'bar'*2; s4 = 'bar'*2; print(id(s3) == id(s4)). А такая выведет уже False: s3 = 'bar'*2500; s4 = 'bar'*2500; print(id(s3) == id(s4))

Comment: питон выделаят 4096 байта на каждый символ, соответственно на умножение bar должно быть рассчитано максимум 1365 байт, на один символ - 4096.

Comment: @Данилкин Не желаете оформить как ответ?

Comment: @Данилкин "4096 байта на каждый символ" - что такое "символ" ?

Comment: @ХачатурСаркисян На мой взгляд (но я не уверен на 100%) фокус в том, что 'bar' - это **константа**, а 'bar' * 2500 - это **выражение**! Интерпретатор может сравнить и оптимизировать при совпадении **константы**, но не **выражения**

Comment: @Sergey Самый прикол, что некоторые выражения он всё же может тоже осознать как константу. Но это сильно зависит от версии интерпретатора

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поздравляю, вы наткнулись на явление, которое называется `string interning` и которое есть не только в Python, но и в других языках (`Java`, `C#` и др.), потому что строки занимают довольно много памяти и если они часто повторяются, то хочется сэкономить память и не хранить много копий одинаковых строк.

Но детали реализации тут очень сильно зависят от конкретного интерпретатора, на разных версиях `Python` строки могут попадать в [пул строк](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%BB_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA) при разных условиях - в зависимости от длины строк, сложности их "вычисления" и т.д. Строки, задаваемые не явно в коде программы, а создаваемые в процессе работы с учётом значений переменных, уже не попадают в пул автоматически, но могут быть помещены туда с помощью специальной функции, в `Python` это функция `sys.intern`.

Чуть более подробно можно почитать, например, [здесь](https://github.com/satwikkansal/wtfpython#-strings-can-be-tricky-sometimes). Вообще, очень рекомендую почитать весь текст **"WTF Python!"** по ссылке, а не только указанный абзац, там много интересного и про внутреннее устройство и про необычное поведение `Python` в каких-то ситуациях.

Я провёл небольшой эксперимент в **Google Colab**. Получилось, что там `Python` интернирует строки длиной до 20 символов, не более.

```
for i in range(1,100000):
    a = eval(f'"a" * {i}')
    b = eval(f'"a" * {i}')
    if(id(a) != id(b)):
        print(f'String interning works for string len <= {i - 1}')
        break
```

Вывод:

```
String interning works for string len <= 20
```

Потом попробовал принудительное интернирование. Оно работало пока не кончилась память:

```
from sys import intern
i = 1
while True:
    print(i, flush=True)
    a = intern("a" * i)
    b = intern("a" * i)
    if(id(a) != id(b)):
        print(f'String interning works for string len < {i}')
        break
    i *= 10
```

Вывод:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000
100000000
1000000000
10000000000
WARNING:root:kernel restarted
```